# Configuring asp.net web applications. Best practices

Tags: asp.net, configuration

There is a lot of configurable information for a web-site:

- UI messages
- Number of records used in pagination & other UI parameters
- Cache duration for web-pages & timeouts
- Route maps & site structure
- ...

There are many approaches to store all this information also:

- AppSettings  (web.config)
- Custom sections (web.config)
- External xml/text files referred from web.config
- Internal static class(es) of constants
- Database table(s)
- ...

What approaches do you usually choose for your tasks & what approaches do you find unsuitable?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these are all very subjective and depend on the type of site you have, but here are my two cents:

**UI messages** - if multi-lingual, store them in resource files

**Number of records used in pagination & other UI parameters** - I like to make this selectable by the users, if using jquery to do this plugins such as tablesorter and tablesorter.pager make it easy

**Cache duration for web-pages & timeouts** - really depends on how time sensitive your data is.  If content is updated frequently, you may not want to cache it for long.  But if there is a lot of code to retrieve and organize the data, you may want to cache it for longer to improve performance.

**Route maps & site structure** - really dependent on what type of site you have and whether it will benefit the users

**AppSettings (web.config)** - good for constants and items that won't change often, or are specific to that installation, such as base url, webservice url, google api keys, etc

**Custom sections (web.config)** - can be good for settings that don't conform well to the dictionary format, one key to one value.

**External xml/text files referred from web.config** - I use this as a last resort, might nust be preference, but I hate using file i/o on the site.

**Internal static class(es) of constants** - Good approach to store settings that are loaded from the db, to avoid a db hit everytime you need the values

**Database table(s)** - when using db tables for settings, I prefer to load them into a static class and refresh it periodically, to avoid having to hit the db everytime I need the data

Comment: wrt to 2 last points, Cache with callback option would be better(than static)?